# Custom post type and taxonomy cross registration

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I intend to set up the following:

- CPT: job, team-member

They share

- taxonomy: location

When I register location, I do this:

```
$args = array(
   ....
   'hierarchical'  => false,
   'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'location' ),
);
register_taxonomy( 'location', array( 'team-member', 'job' ), $args );
```

My question: Do I need the 'taxonomies' line below

```
register_post_type('job', array(
   ....
   'rewrite'     => array('slug' => 'careers'),
   'taxonomies'  => array('location'),
));
```

Explanation is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need both, one of them is enough. However you need to do it in a order when thing you are adding support to is already registers.

So in first case you need to define CPT *before* taxonomy and in second case *after*.

The third way would be to use `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` which let's you do this after *both* are registered, regardless of order.